# How do I set the proxy for the MIP SDK for C# .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, .net-4.8, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am having issues setting the proxy for the MIP SDK, following the documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/concept-mip-proxies). My application uses the Microsoft.InformationProtection.File nuget package to interact with the MIP SDK. When we originally intergated this into the software we were able to set the proxy for the MIP SDK using the command "netsh winhttp set proxy [http://127.0.0.1:8080"](http://127.0.0.1:8080%22). This seems to no longer be working with the MIP SDK as I am not seeing the traffic in the proxy logs. I am not 100% sure if this started occuring after we updated the packages for our MIP intergation or not.